# Program which counts numbers of words using pointers to an array

Tags: c, pointers

I am a beginner at C programming and I am trying to understand how to use pointer with arrays .
I created a program which counts the number of words in array but why it runs when I use * (* (array+i)) and when I use *(array+i) does not work ??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    
    char array[10][100]={"vass","loup","loooooooo","vap","lol"};
    int i=0 , j=0;
    int counter=0;
    /*for(i=0 ; *(array+i)!=NULL ; i++)
    {   
        counter++;
    }*/
    
    for(i=0; *(*(array+i))!=NULL; i++)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    for(j=0; j <counter ; j++)
    {
        printf("\n pointer array %s", *(array+j));
       //   printf("\n double pointer array %s",*(*(array+j)));
        printf("\n    array      %s", (array+j));
    }

    printf("the words are %d", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing `*(array+i)` instead of `array[i]`?

Comment: I wanted to do an another approach I know that I can do with your way

Answer (score 0):

When you use `*(array+i)` you only point to the right most array which is 100 of length. Each pointer step you nest from exterior like `*(*(array + i))` you will access towards left most array. For you to figure out the case, take this example:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

#define WORD_LENGTH 100
#define ROW_COUNT   10

int main () {
    
    char array[ROW_COUNT][WORD_LENGTH]={"vass","loup","loooooooo","vap","lol"};
    int i=0;
    int counter=0;

    // Here we copy the pointer because the original one must preserve its value
    char *parray = array;
    for(i=0; i<ROW_COUNT; i++) {
        /* 
        * 2 printfs but you will the same characters in array style the compiler handles the
        * addition of the second array length automatically.
        * But in pointer style we need to handle the addition in order to point to the
        * next row or word. That's why the first pointer you commented out can only access to
        * the inner (right most array which is 100 of length) array.
        */
        printf("array\t %c \n", array[i][0]); // Compiler advances adds WORD_LENGTH to the pointer automatically
        printf("arrayp\t %c \n", **(array+i)); // Compiler advances adds WORD_LENGTH to the pointer automatically
        printf("parray\t %c \n", *parray); // Compiler does not handle the addition of WORD_LENGTH
        parray += WORD_LENGTH; // So we have to handle it in order to point to the next row or word
    }
    
    for(i=0; *(*(array+i))!=NULL; i++)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    
    printf("the words are %d\n", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**
The output of the program:

```
array    v
arrayp   v 
parray   v 
array    l 
arrayp   l 
parray   l 
array    l 
arrayp   l 
parray   l 
array    v 
arrayp   v 
parray   v 
array    l 
arrayp   l 
parray   l 
array     
arrayp    
parray    
array     
arrayp    
parray    
array     
arrayp    
parray    
array     
arrayp    
parray    
array     
arrayp    
parray    
the words are 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The notation `*(array+i)` that you're using means: dereferencing a pointer called `array`, but `array` is a pointer to pointer, because you declared like that. Line #1: `char array[10][100]`, two dimensions array means, pointer to pointer.

So for you program works correctly you need to dereferencing the pointer to pointer, using a double *.

`*(array+i)` here only dereference one pointer, returning the second pointer

`* (* (array+i))` the correct dereferencing